# Facebook Graph API user likes.summary(total_count) is different than count of returned data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In response json from api call I got `likes.summary(total_count)` which is for one user e.g. 677 however total count of returned page objects is only 443. I tired same call from my app and also from graph api explorer and `total_count` is always the same, so are pages. I didn't found anything about it in documentation nor google is helpful with this. Why is there this difference, or am I missing something?

Comment: When you try that request in Graph API Explorer, it shows the following debug message: _“total_count represents the approximate number of nodes on the likes edge. The actual number of results returned might be different depending on privacy settings.”_

Comment: yeah I know about it, however even when I try it on my own account, count of  pages which I see I like is different then what I got from api. I went through all pages in pages tab on my news feed wall and total_count is different then what I really see. I thought that it could be total count of what I liked from my first log in so I tried to like new page and then unlike it, nothing changed. If it would be only about privacy settings of page, then I would see all pages in pages tab and number should be the same as total_count.